# remove some rows from array based on some condition

Tags: php

I have an array which contains three column Id, productcode, stock

How do i remove old stock entries from array?

I can remove it by loop but looking for easy solution.

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4353
            [TotalStock] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4354
            [TotalStock] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4353
            [TotalStock] => 60
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4355
            [TotalStock] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4353
            [TotalStock] => 20
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4356
            [TotalStock] => 40
        )

)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4354
            [TotalStock] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4355
            [TotalStock] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4353
            [TotalStock] => 60
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [ProductCode] => 4356
            [TotalStock] => 40
        )

)
```

Comment: How do you know which is old ? There is no timestamp key etc

Comment: based on total stock value and combination(composite key) of "Id" and "ProductCode"

Comment: Is Id really always the same?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yesy it will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array.

```
sort($products);
```

Since the Id is always the same, this will sort the inner arrays by Product code ascending, then by TotalStock ascending.

Then reindex by ProductCode.

```
$newest = array_column($products, null, 'ProductCode');
```

You'll end up with the last entry for each ProductCode.

Note that the simple `sort()` depends on the columns already being in the order you want to sort by. If that order of columns changes, you'll need to use a `usort()` instead so you can specify the sort order.

Comment: simple and best answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply need to overwrite sub-array (internal array) for a specific productId to get latest. We can use the `ProductCode` as key to filter out duplicates:

```php
$csv_mod = array(); // initializing variable to store latest values
foreach ($csv as $obj) {
    if ( isset($csv_mod[$obj['ProductCode']]) 
         && $csv_mod[$obj['ProductCode']]['TotalStock'] < $obj['TotalStock'] ) {

        // This will overwrite if a duplicate value with higher stock appears
        $csv_mod[$obj['ProductCode']] = $obj;
    } else {
        // First time encountered in the loop
        $csv_mod[$obj['ProductCode']] = $obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for suggestion, but do we really need to reset ? It should not matter I think! Moreover, this mod array can help sometimes, when OP just needs list of all `ProductCode` values, he can simply use `array_keys($csv_mod)`

Comment: I want max stock value, check updated array, your code will return stock = 20, but it should be 60.

Comment: @JunedAnsari you changed your requirement later; anyways, I am editing the answer as per your new requirement